# React Route Navlink

Tags: reactjs, router

I have problem
here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import NavLink from 'react-router-dom';
import s from './Navbar.module.css';

const Navbar = () => {
    return <nav className={s.nav}>
        <div className={s.item}>
            <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
        </div>
        <div className={`${s.item} ${s.active}`}>
            <a href="/dialogs">Messages</a>
        </div>
        <div className={s.item}>
            <a href="">News</a>
        </div>
        <div className={s.item}>
            <a>Music</a>
        </div>
        <div className={s.item}>
            <a>Settings</a>
        </div>
    </nav>       
};
export default Navbar;
```

It works but when I change  to NavLink - White screen is coming
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you change the `href` to `to` and `a` to `Link`? Also on white screen check your console for debugging

Comment: Yes i try to change in such way 
<NavLink to="/dialogs">  Messages </NavLink>